# "War Games" Tour

Tags: usa, military, colorado

I think a lot of people remember the movie [*War Games*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086567/), and while I don't think that playing the "Global Thermonuclear War" simulation on the real military system is possible or even a good idea, I was wondering if one could still visit [Cheyenne mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheyenne_Mountain_nuclear_bunker) station for [NORAD](http://www.norad.mil/)?

The most current information I was able to find was from [1999 Baltimore Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheyenne_Mountain_nuclear_bunker) about limiting tours of the mountain but nothing about the cancellation of them.

Would be cool to see: [image]
(movies still from War Games borrowed from IMDB)

Comment: You do realize that it's against Stack Exchange's terms to use copyright images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Cheyenne Mountain](http://www.norad.mil/AboutNORAD/CheyenneMountainAirForceStation.aspx) does offer tours, but not to members of the public. That program was [scaled down in 1999](http://articles.baltimoresun.com/1999-01-31/news/9902010324_1_cheyenne-mountain-inside-the-mountain-space-command) and discontinued after September 11.

[TripAdvisor reviews](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g33364-d144383-Reviews-NORAD_North_American_Aerospace_Defense_Command-Colorado_Springs_El_Paso_County_Colo.html#REVIEWS) from a few years ago suggest that "Friends and Family" tours can be scheduled on Fridays, but you must be invited and escorted by someone who works at the facility, and must be a member of the U.S. military or be pre-screened by the Department of Defense. I could not find screening information online, but for comparison, it takes 4-6 weeks to get approval to visit the U.S. Naval Observatory in Washington, D.C.— and unlike Cheyenne Mountain, that is a facility that does advertise public access. You may not be missing much; most of NORAD's operations have moved elsewhere.

The easiest military-related attraction to visit in Colorado Springs is the [National Museum of World War II Aviation](http://www.worldwariiaviation.org/), located on the grounds of the [cos](/questions/tagged/cos) airport and open several days a week. The [Peterson Air and Space Museum](http://www.petemuseum.org/) is also open to the public, but [Peterson Air Force Base](http://www.peterson.af.mil/) where it is located is not, so you will need [prior authorization](http://www.petemuseum.org/files/Misc/VisitorAccess20120822.pdf).

Fortunately, there are many more easily-accessed places to sate your appetite for Cold War-era military facilities: the [National Atomic Testing Museum](http://www.nationalatomictestingmuseum.org/) in Las Vegas, [Greenbrier Bunker](http://www.greenbrier.com/Activities/The-Bunker/Bunker-Tours.aspx) in West Virginia, the [Titan Missile Museum](http://www.titanmissilemuseum.org/) in Arizona, the [Submarine Force Museum and USS Nautilus](http://www.ussnautilus.org/) in Connecticut (adjacent to the Naval Submarine Base New London, which allows public access on certain days but doesn't offer much to see), and the [Minuteman Missile National Historic Site](http://www.nps.gov/mimi/) in South Dakota.

Comment: I want to see the [Big Board](http://www.uta.edu/honors/faculty/petruso/DrStrangelove2.jpg)! :)

Comment: @Karlson According to a [*Stars & Stripes* blog post](http://www.stripes.com/blogs/the-rumor-doctor/the-rumor-doctor-1.104348/does-norad-have-a-wargames-computer-1.114848) on the matter, those control centers and conference rooms are sadly just Hollywood imagination— the real ones are somewhat [less impressive](http://www.stripes.com/polopoly_fs/1.114850.1281964911!/image/614324306.jpg_gen/derivatives/landscape_804/614324306.jpg). Or at least that's what they would have us believe :). Instead of WOPR they play GTA now.

Comment: Dang it!!!  I'm getting too far behind the times!